# Are these three articles on The DAO Pattern still relevant in ADO.NET for .NET 3.5 and .NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, dao

I found three related articles on using the DAO pattern with ADO.NET (they're a bit dated, but they seem to make good points about the nature of ADO.NET as of VS2005).

If you were a developer using VS2010 would the points in these articles still hold up?

- [Part One](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ADONETOOP.aspx)
- [Part Two](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/AdoNetForOopPart2.aspx)
- [Part Three](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/ADONETOOPPart3.aspx?q=ADO.NET%20for%20the%20Object-Oriented%20Programmer%20%E2%80%93%20Part%20two)

(P.S. I'm a Java developer who recently was picked up for a C#/ASP.NET position)

Answer (score 1):

ADO.NET still work in all version of .NET
For some uses it might be just faster and easier to start with [LINQ to SQL](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/05/19/using-linq-to-sql-part-1.aspx) or the Entity Framework

Comment: I heard that LINQ to SQL was being dropped (or was dropped in 2008) by MS.

Comment: (but that LINQ to Objects was still in the game.)

Comment: MS changed their mind back. I'm using LINQ to SQL in VS2008. No problem

Comment: Or try EF http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/details/363647ae-8c44-4ed7-a310-1b94629f1671

Comment: Glad to hear they changed their mind back, there were two people at work and the one seemed to like LINQ to SQL while the other said he thought it was deprecated.

Comment: @leeand: LINQ to SQL is limited to SQL Server and also is limited to a one-to-one mapping between your code and the database. For instance, you have to navigate through junction tables to handle many to many relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I would ignore five year old articles as a general rule. Think how much the industry has changed in the past five years.

I would use Entity Framework instead, and skip right over straight ADO.NET and LINQ to SQL.

Comment: I'd do that if I could, but that's not what they're using at work.  They said they're using LINQ to Objects. (and ASP.NET...oh well I'll live with it )  LINQ to Objects sounds okay though.

Comment: LINQ to Objects is used for objects in memory. ASP.NET also has nothing to do with database access. So I'm not sure what they're using for database access.

Comment: I understand that the EF is great for creating what people in the open source / rails / grails world call a scaffolding (and this probably saves you alot of time!) If I'm right about that.

Comment: @leeand: your perhaps I don't understand what they call a "scaffolding". EF allows you to create a conceptual model of your data, and then to map it to the underlying database. As a result, your code does not need to deal with low-level issues like junction tables, table inheritance, etc. The latest releases improve the story by allowing you to use POCO classes, customize the code generation, etc.

Comment: POCO being Plain Old C# Objects right?

Comment: @leeand: or Plain Old Class Objects